# Oracle Apex 20.1 Error: Error processing validation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to create a validation for a page in an application on oracle apex. Below is the pl/sql function body (returning boolean) I have:

```
declare v_equipid integer;
begin
        SELECT count(*) into v_equipid from equipment
        WHERE equipstatus = 'available' and equipID = :P3_EquipID;

    if v_equipid = 1 then
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    end if;
end;
```

It is used to check whether the EquipID submitted has equipstatus = 'available'. After I run the application and submit the form, it gives the following error:

Error: Error processing validation.

- is_internal_error: true
- is_common_runtime_error: false
- apex_error_code: APEX.VALIDATION.UNHANDLED_ERROR
- ora_sqlcode: -6502
- ora_sqlerrm: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_VALIDATION", line 846
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_VALIDATION", line 846
- error_backtrace: ORA-06512: at "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_VALIDATION", line 846
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_VALIDATION", line 846
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_VALIDATION", line 1029

I don't know how to fix this and I would appreciate your help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Numeric or value error, eh?

This is what might be causing the problem:

```
and equipID = :P3_EquipID;
```

What is `equipID`'s datatype? If it is a `NUMBER`, try

```
and equipID = to_number(:P3_EquipID);
```

---

As that's not the case (as you commented), would this help?

```
declare 
  v_equipid number;
begin
  SELECT count(*) 
    into v_equipid 
    from equipment
    WHERE equipstatus = 'available' 
      and equipID = :P3_EquipID;

  return v_equipid = 1;
end;
```

Comment: EquipID is a number, but this seems to not be the problem as adding to_number didn't fix the problem. But thank you!

Comment: I see. I guess `equipstatus` *is* a string, right? I also added some more code; see if it helps.

Comment: equipstatus is Varchar2, and oracle doesn't allow `return v_equipid` and I got this error: ORA-06550: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type.

Comment: I didn' say to retun that. Look again.

Comment: Sorry, I just tried `return v_equipid = 1`, it is still numeric or value error

Comment: That's insane :(. What happens if you remove all that code and just `return true;` to see what happens. Then try to add line-by-line of your code, running the page after every edit, until you find the culprit.

Comment: It seems like the problem is this line `SELECT count(*) into v_equipid from equipment`

Answer (score 0):

The key to developing in apex is debugging your own code. That takes a bit of getting used to.  Research on how to debug your apex app and instrument your pl/sql code, there is plenty of documentation available on the web.

You could just debug the validation by running that pl/sql in SQL workshop. Replace your `RETURN TRUE/FALSE` statements with `dbms_output.put_line('true/false')` to get the result. Running it in sql workshop will give you the exact line number. ORA-06502 usually means that a variable or column of type NUMBER is assigned a value of datatype VARCHAR2 (or another datatype that cannot be casted back to a number) .

Make sure you remove the dbms_output statements again when you move the code back to apex.

You could also debug your process in apex itself by using apex_debug, have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_debug.htm#AEAPI29182) for a full overview of the functionality, something like this:

```
DECLARE
  v_equipid NUMBER; --integer is deprecated, should not be used
BEGIN
  -- put double quotes around the %0 to make any trailing/leading characters visible.
  apex_debug.info(
      p_message => 'Start of validation,  P3_EQUIPID = "%0"',
      p0        => :P3_EQUIPID);
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO v_equipid
    FROM equipment
   WHERE equipstatus = 'available' AND
         equipid = :P3_EQUIPID;
  apex_debug.info(
      p_message => 'After SELECT INTO,  v_equipid = "%0"',
      p0        => v_equipid);
  IF v_equipid = 1 THEN
    RETURN true;
  ELSE
    RETURN false;
  END IF;
END;
```

Enable debug in the developer toolbar and investigate debug for your page. The messages you put in there should be available in the debug logs. The messages you put in the code after the error is thrown will not  be visible since that code will not be executed.

Comment: I debugged the code in SQL workshop, for some reason it worksed fine there with `dbms_output.put_line('true/false')` and returned the correct true/false values. However when I pasted it into the application again and changed it back to to `RETURN TRUE/FALSE`, the error was still there.

Comment: What are datatypes of columns  equipstatus  and equipid ?

Comment: Equipstatus is varchar2 and equipID is number

Comment: Any possibility that :P3_EQUIPID is not a number ? Maybe it has leading/trailing spaces or control characters ?

Comment: It should be a number, just to be sure I changed it to `to_number(trim(:P3_EquipID))` but it still didn't work.

Comment: Next thing I'd do is put apex_debug.info calls on every line then run debug to check exactly where it fails. You can also use it to check what the value is of P3_EQUIPID, just to be sure.

Comment: Sorry I am not quite sure how apex_debug.info works, could you please explain it? Thanks a lot and sorry for the trouble

Comment: I can't find the message in the debug logs, I'm not sure if I'm looking at the right place. Should message be found on the same page where I view the errors? Thank you

Comment: Did you check the web and/or the documentation on how to use debug in oracle apex ? If you get stuck I'll help you out