# How Do I Solve Error Processing Validation in Oracle Apex 20.1

Tags: oracle-apex

apex 20.1
database: 19c

To test I tried function body: (returning boolean):

```
BEGIN
RETURN true;
end;
```

Still getting Error processing validation.

- ora_sqlerrm: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_200200.WWV_FLOW_VALIDATION", line 816
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_200200.WWV_FLOW_VALIDATION", line 816

similar to [Oracle Apex 20.1 Error: Error processing validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63186757/oracle-apex-20-1-error-error-processing-validation)  but it appears to be unresolved. No answer accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to validate using the value from a column and also an item whose value was loaded when the page was loaded.

Originally I added the item to the table region. In validation> editable region I had selected the table region. This caused the error processing validation.

I put the item generated on page load in its own region and changed validation> editable region to -select- and now it works.